# Android Bluetooth BLE what connection's configuration parameters can I modify

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am developing an app working with bluetooth peripherals one LE. Everything works fine, I got characteristics services etc. I can get values from sensors etc.

The problem is that from time to time app 'freezes' while getting values, sometimes peripheral return wrong values. I can't figure out why does that happen.

So what i want to try is to configure some parameters about the connection between the phone and the device. That's why I would like to know which parameters I can set while connecting (for ex. on GATT's instance, but not only). I tried to search for some info about it, but it's so little of information.

That's why I would like a list of parameters that would change the performance of my connection between devices.

The last thing I want to do is to change everything on the peripheral (adafruit) side..

Comment: You have answered yourself correctly. There is not so much you can do using Android's API. You should post your changes as an answer to your question, rather than put the answer in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I posted answer as you said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As no one answered my question and I went through whole stackoverflow questions tagged by the topic (android bluetooth connection) I am going to share what I found out. Well, to be true I didn't find much. Most questions about android bluetooth are left without answer or without proper / satysfying answer. Is developers knowledge about BLE so low? Really? That's shame. But jumping to the answer...

What I figured out is that, you can't change almost anything about connection on your android phone. It's all in the business of the peripheral. I found only one parameter that can be 'modified', which is "connection time interval" (time between each data transfer). I marked 'modified', because you can't set requested number (milliseconds). You can set only 3 parameters for your gatt connection: (with requestConnectionPriority() method)

```
CONNECTION_PRIORITY_BALANCED, CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH and CONNECTION_PRIORITY_LOW_POWER
```

More info (but still not much) (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestConnectionPriority(int))

But I am not sure for what time they change the interval. It's all you can change. You can't change supervision timeout (which is hardcoded to 20 s), you can't change anything. All's left for the peripheral configuration. Mobile os API don't allow us to do low level settings.

If anyone knows something more, please share!